# Navegation Drawer with permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to know if there is any way that the side menu can be shown only if you have a higher range.
I am making an application where if you log in and your level is 1 then it happens to an activity, but in case of being level 2 or 3 it happens to an activity that has a drop-down menu, my question: is this possible? If this is how I could do it and if not, any variation that you may have from my idea? That is not that everyone has the drop-down menu but those of level 1 when trying to press it do not leave them